# Class cannot be found by reflection when usings are inside namespace and not outside. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, namespaces, using

We have some handlers, these handlers are instantiated in IoC by reflection because they cannot be referenced. This worked just fine until I came with StyleCop and moved usings of some handlers inside the namespace. Suddenly, our algorithm could not get handler for the particular command. I found out that this seemingly insignificant change did the break.

Handler before change:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using AccessManagement.Common.Configuration;
using AccessManagement.DirectoryServices;
using AccessManagement.Management.AdContact.Commands;
using AccessManagement.Management.AdUser;
using AccessManagement.{NotForYourEyes1};
using AccessManagement.{NotForYourEyes1}.Enums;
using AccessManagement.{NotForYourEyes1}.Extensions;
using AccessManagement.{NotForYourEyes1}.Models;

using Architecture.Core;

using {NotForYourEyes2}.Common;
using {NotForYourEyes2}.Common.Configuration;

namespace AccessManagement.Management.AdContact
{


    [EnableHandler]
    public class MoveAdContactHandler : IHandleRequest<MoveAdContact, AdUserResponse>
    {
        public Task<AdUserResponse> Handle(MoveAdContact request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
```

Handler after change:

```
namespace AccessManagement.Management.AdContact
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using AccessManagement.Common.Configuration;
    using AccessManagement.DirectoryServices;
    using AccessManagement.Management.AdContact.Commands;
    using AccessManagement.Management.AdUser;
    using AccessManagement.{NotForYourEyes1};
    using AccessManagement.{NotForYourEyes1}.Enums;
    using AccessManagement.{NotForYourEyes1}.Extensions;
    using AccessManagement.{NotForYourEyes1}.Models;

    using Architecture.Core;

    using {NotForYourEyes2}.Common;
    using {NotForYourEyes2}.Common.Configuration;

    [EnableHandler]
    public class MoveAdContact2Handler : IHandleRequest<MoveAdContact, AdUserResponse>
    {
```

Algorithm registering handler to IoC container:

```
    private static void RegisterBusHandlers(IServiceRegistry serviceRegistry, Func<ILifetime> handlersLifetime)
    {
        var handlerProvider = new HandlerRegistrator((i, t) =>
        {
            serviceRegistry.Register(i, t, handlersLifetime());
        });

        var handlerTypes =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                    .GetAssemblies()
                    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                    .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<EnableHandlerAttribute>() != null);

        foreach (var handlerType in handlerTypes)
        {
            handlerProvider.RegisterHandler(handlerType);
        }
    }
```

To summarize -- handler before the change is found well, handler after the change is not found at all. This is sort of brain twister for me and my team. Can anyone explain this behavior please?

Comment: I doubt it might have such effect. Maybe StyleCop changed something else too?

Comment: @Evk Nah, just this. I swear. Checked with git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those `using` directives will now be used *before* considering enclosing namespaces. You presumably used to be locating types inside either `AccessManagement.Management` or `AccessManagement` and are now instead resolving the same type names to type(s) within the namespaces declared by those `using` directives.

Which ones, only you can determine.

E.g. if there are two different `EnableHandlerAttribute` types then your registration code may now be registering completely different types now.

Comment: I reread several times but still didn't get it. Can you provide some example of the difference?

Comment: @Evk - imagine two types called `SpongeBob`. One is located inside `AccessManagement.Common.Configuration`. The other is located inside `AccessManagement`. Before the change, the one that was located was the one in `AccessManagement`. After the change, the one located is inside `AccessManagement.Common.Configuration`. That's because previously, the search used the namespace hierarchy first and only when it reached the global namespace did it use the `using` directives located there.

Comment: But we are talking about discovering types with reflection here. I believe there is no such thing as using directives after code is compiled. Not to mention code in question discovers all types from all assemblies, so should discover both types in this case.

Comment: @Evk - yes, but if you're using reflection to, say, try to find all types that implement `IThingy`, and `IThingy` is appearing as a type name in your code and *the specific* `IThingy` that is being picked up during compilation has changed, you'll now get different results from your reflection. It's rare for reflection code to be *entirely* devoid of type names. E.g. in Querts registration code, imagine that a different `EnableHandlerAttribute` is now being used.

Comment: So to clarify, in this case you mean that there might be two `EnableHandlerAttribute` in different namespaces and now different one is picked after the change.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, yes, you are right. That's most likely it. I couldn't believe my eyes, but we actually have two same named types in one solution :/ What a shame. Thanks a lot